# Adding HTML web app to WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, import

I have created a small application locally on my machine using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I am using a plugin to run the JavaScript on the site. My small application loads different pictures from drop down lists and uses a SendMail JavaScript function as well. How can I add this page as one of my WordPress pages? I used a BlankSlate plugin to clean one of my pages up and whenever I paste my code into the page it gets scrambled and doesent work. It loads my drop down lists and some titles but pictures are gone and background isnt present. I am new to using WordPress and I want to add this small app to my site. Any help would be great or suggestions and how to copy it over.   ( Sorry for the messy, unorganized code. Still learning and practicing, but this is what I am trying to turn into a page )

```
<html lang="en"><head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content=" A page for exploring html documents">
    <title>BuildIt-AR App</title>   
           <head>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

    <style> 
.body {max-width:1920px; margin:0 auto;}
.centered {max-width:720px; margin:0 auto;}
        .floatLeft {
        float:left;}
        select {
display:block; clear:both;  
            }    
              .myBox{

           clear:both; 
            max-width: 375px;
            max-height: 225px;
            padding-top:275px;

            }
        .textlines {
            padding-top:350px;

        }



        body{
            background-image: url("https://www.xmple.com/wallpaper/grey-gradient-linear-1920x1080-c2-708090-dcdcdc-a-285-f-14.svg");
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            border: 5px inset lightgrey;
        }

        font{

  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;       
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 350%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-shadow: 2.2px 1.5px grey;              
}
            select{

        }


    </style>



    <script type="application/javascript">
        var pictureList1 = [
            "http://i66.tinypic.com/xds135.png",
            "http://i68.tinypic.com/28cdhxh.png",
            "http://i66.tinypic.com/169s4mc.png", 
        ];


        function change_image(id) {
            var idx = document.getElementById('picDD').value - 1; // javascript is zero-indexed
            document.getElementById('pic').src = pictureList1[idx];
            y = document.getElementById("picDD");

          //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
          document.getElementById("stock").value = stock[y.selectedIndex];
        }
                 var pictureList2 = [
            "http://i65.tinypic.com/2wmqefs.png",
            "http://i63.tinypic.com/s4za11.png",
            "http://i66.tinypic.com/6e3ibq.png",

        ];
        function change_image2(id) {
            var idx = document.getElementById('picDD2').value - 1; // javascript is zero-indexed
            document.getElementById('pic2').src = pictureList2[idx];
            y = document.getElementById("picDD2");

          //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
          document.getElementById("body").value = body[y.selectedIndex];
        }
                 var pictureList3 = [
            "http://i65.tinypic.com/2n9dslt.png",
            " http://i65.tinypic.com/289h35y.png",
            "http://i64.tinypic.com/vxnpzd.png",

        ];
        function change_image3(id) {
            var idx = document.getElementById('picDD3').value - 1; // javascript is zero-indexed
            document.getElementById('pic3').src = pictureList3[idx];
        y = document.getElementById("picDD3");

          //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
          document.getElementById("barrel").value = barrel[y.selectedIndex];
        }




var barrel = new Array();
var body = new Array();
var stock = new Array();

barrel[0] = "Assault Barrel $89.95";
body[0] = "BlackOut Body $231.95";
stock[0] = "Slide Stock $78.95";

barrel[1] = "Sniper Barrel $395.95";
body[1] = "SlideFire Body $278.95";
stock[1] = "Fold Stock $178.95";

barrel[2] = "Tactical Barrel $278.95";
body[2] = "Green Body $134.95";
stock[2] = "Steady Stock $78.95";

barrel[3] = 4;
body[3] = "asmith";
stock[3] = "Andy Smith";


   // function change_image3() {
        //x = document.getElementById("users");


    // 
         function sendMail() {
var link = "mailto:example@gmail.com"
         + "?cc=gunbuilder@builditar.com"
         + "&subject=" + escape("BuildIt-AR Order Form")
         + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('name').value + "\n" + document.getElementById('barrel').value + "\n" + document.getElementById('body').value + "\n" + document.getElementById('stock').value);



  window.location.href = link;
}

    </script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="centered">
<div class="floatLeft">
       <img id="pic" src="http://i66.tinypic.com/xds135.png" class="myBox">
    <select id="picDD" onchange="change_image();">
          <option value="1" selected="">Stock #1</option>
          <option value="2">Stock #2</option>
          <option value="3">Stock #3</option>
          </select>
    </div></div>


    <div class="floatLeft">
    <img id="pic2" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/2wmqefs.png" class="myBox">
    <select id="picDD2" onchange="change_image2();">
        <option value="1" selected="">Body #1</option>
        <option value="2">Body #2</option>
        <option value="3">Body #3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="floatLeft">  
    <img id="pic3" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/vxnpzd.png" class="myBox">
    <select id="picDD3" onchange="change_image3();">
         <option value="1" selected="">Barrel #1</option>
         <option value="2">Barrel #2</option>
         <option value="3">Barrel #3</option>
        </select>
       </div> 



 <div class="textlines">    
<input type="text" placeholder="<Name>" id="name">
<p>Barrel <input type="text" id="barrel" name="id" ></p>
<p>Body <input type="text" id="body" name="username" ></p>
<p>Stock <input type="text" id="stock" name="full_name" ></p>
```

```
    <font size="10">BuildIt-AR</font>
<button onclick="sendMail(); return false">Send</button>


 </body></html>
```

Comment: You probably want to create a shortcode for the whole thing. But make sure all of your js is properly enqueued.

Comment: provide your code

Comment: Code added to post

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to create a custom shortcode for this. Something like [buildit], this code then get's replaced by your app code.

You could use a free plugin like [Snippy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/snippy/) to do this. Full disclosure, I'm the author of the plugin.

Snippy lets you can create your own shortcodes and pick names for them. Then you can add pieces of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to the shortcode (*in Snippy these are named "bits"*). You then place the shortcode on a page or post, and Snippy will output your HTML instead. A lot easier than learning the WordPress API or modify PHP files.

In your situation, I would advise to copy all the HTML inside the `<body>` tag and add it to an HTML "bit". You can move the font embed `<link>` in there as well. Snippy will take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page http://your-site.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page then create a new page template in your theme folder

```
wp-content/your-theme/page-{slug}.php
```

and in that file add your app.  If you like you can even create custom header and footer files too.

```
wp-content/your-theme/header-app.php
wp-content/your-theme/footer-app.php
```

Then in your page-{slug}.php file just add

```
<?php get_header('app'); ?>
<!-- your content -->
<?php get_footer('app'); ?>
```